# Opencv Face detection slower

Tags: c++, c, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a big image say ( 720 x 1290 ). If I pass the continuous frames to face detection, it's getting delayed, and the display from the camera lags.

What I did is I have re-sized the image to ( 480 x 640 ). The face detection is pretty decent, and camera is not lagging.

My question here, I have detected a face and got the coordinates of the face in the image (480 x 640). Now, I need to draw the rectangle in (720 x 1290), but I have the face coordinates only for ( 480 x 640).

Now with the face co-ordinates available for ( 720 x 1290 ), how do I draw the rectangle in ( 480 x 640 ) image?

Any example would be helpful.

Comment: multiply by each dimensions scale rate?

Comment: oh.. tell me how do you solve this problem "if one orange cost is 5$ what is the cost of 10 oranges?" if rectangle size in 480X640 is HxW then in 720X1290 will be 720/480 * H x 1290/640 * W where W-width & H-height...

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize

Answer (score 1):

If the location of the face is stored in cvRect faceRect, and the original image is stored in cvMat OriginalImage, try this:

```
cvRect enlargedFrame;
enlargedFrame.x = faceRect.x*originalImage.cols/720;
enlargedFrame.y = faceRect.y*originalImage.rows/480;
enlargedFrame.width = faceRect.width*originalImage.cols/720;
enlargedFrame.height = faceRect.height*originalImage.rows/480;
```

Now draw a rectangle using the coordinates of enlargedFrame.

If you decide to crop the image to make it even smaller, this gets more complicated. In that case, you could use affine transforms.